# MEF: How to refer to a custom interface as Export/Import without creating project dependencies

Tags: c#, mef

I'm new to MEF. In the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx), both the application and the DLL are within the same Solution, so they can commonly refer to a custom interface (IOperation) as both export and import (which is defined in the application's assembly).

```
[Export(typeof(SimpleCalculator3.IOperation))]
[ExportMetadata("Symbol", '%')]
public class Mod : SimpleCalculator3.IOperation
{
    public int Operate(int left, int right)
    {
        return left % right;
    }
}
```

However I want to be able to create plugins without sharing the main project's source / requiring to link to the assembly. I thought it would be like Pinvokes where if I just defined duplicate and identical interfaces on either side it could work out that they matched, but it seems not.

How can I refer to an interface on the Export side in a standalone project, if the definition of the Import interface is within the application?

The only workaround I can think of is to create a common DLL holding only a definition of the export/import interface templates which both can then refer to?